# C# Class Arrays stored in an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, class

New to multidimensional arrays and a bit stuck on a little project I am working on.

Getting a error when I try to store 2 arrays (student and teacher) in to a course array, when creating them as class arrays

Below is the code from my `main()`

```
Student stud1 = new Student("Alex", "Kelly", DateTime.Parse("14/07/2000"));
Student stud2 = new Student("Tom", "Smith", DateTime.Parse("16/08/198
Student stud3 = new Student("Mary", "Jones", DateTime.Parse("10/01/1998"));

//add students to an array and get the count
Student[] studentArray = new Student[3] { stud1, stud2, stud3 };
int count1 = studentArray.Length;

//add teacher objects
Teacher prof1 = new Teacher("Beckham");
Teacher prof2 = new Teacher("Pele");
Teacher prof3 = new Teacher("Maradonna");
Teacher[] teacherArray = new Teacher[3] { prof1, prof2, prof3 };

 //course Object
 Course course1 = new Course("Programming with C#");
 Course[,] courseList = new Course[,] { {studentArray} , { teacherArray } };
```

I am getting the error on the last line shown, when I try to add the `{ studentArray, teacherArray }` to the `courseList` array.

The error is

> cannot implicitly convert type `Student[]` to `Course`

If I change the array from `Course` to `object [,]` it works fine

Do I need to add something to my class file?

Comment: if you create array of `Course` so you should init it with `Course` but you try init it with `Student` and `Teacher`

Comment: A `Course[,]` array has to contain courses, not arrays of other types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you code can be refactored.

For example, why don't your `Course` class look like:

```
class Course
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Student> Students;
    public List<Teacher> Teachers;
}
```

It is more natural and object-orianted way. In this case you don't need two-dimensional array, and you can use only `List<Course>`.

Also note - in many cases `List<T>` is more convinient then `T[]` array sincу it is resizing automatically.

Comment: Or if he wants a less object oriented approach that achieves a similar behaviour he could do something like using a List<Tuple<Student[], Teacher[]>> llistOfCourses or a List<Tuple<List<Student>, List<Teacher>>> listOfCourses and store his data this way. Of course I would also prefer the object oriented way because properties with names are more informative than item1 and item2, but when you just have 2 properties I believe a list of tuples is acceptable ?!

Comment: @MeAndSomeRandoms well, from original question we can see `Course` itself has at least name, so it it not just tuple of students and teachers collections . Also note - `Tuple` has become available only in .NET 4, so in prior versions you will have to implement it manually.

Comment: Thanks  Andy, and everyone else for their comments and help. List are defo the way to go, and I am more familiar with them.

Answer (score 3):

The error you are experiencing is because `Course` array will only allow objects of `Course` type.  You cannot place other objects or arrays with it.

To resolve your problem, it might be better to have the `Student` and `Teacher` arrays as a properties of the `Course` object.  These can then be assigned values as needed.

See:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx for information on arrays.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx for information on properties.

*Update following edit*

The `object[,]` array will work because `object` is the base type for all other types.  As a result of this, an `object[]` can have any other type assigned to it.  As you indicate you are learning to program so it might be worth reading up on object oriented design - It will help you model your data better.  For a starting point try  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

What you should try to do is use OBJECT ARRAYS . This array will store the the different objects and it will also retain their form . 
Check out this link . Its quite detailed on this topic.
[enter link description here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/object-array)

Comment: Object arrays? In present time, when generics and generic collections exists? Are you kidding?

Answer (score 0):

To extend on a previous answers, always think about how you separate up your data. For example, the Course itself is a very 'static' concept compared to the attendees and the tutors. The Course could even have different dates with different attendees etc but will not change whereas dates and those involved will.

So your model could be:

```
public class CourseSchedule
{
    public CourseSchedule(Course course, Student[] students, Teacher[] teacher)
    {
        this.Course = course;
        ....
    }

    // Some sort of Date too

    public Course Course { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<Teacher> Teachers { get; private set; }
}
```

Multi-dimensional arrays are worth understanding but are specific to certain types of programming - graphics, mathematical transforms etc. You tend to use them for low level coding but for modelling real world structures such as your course booking they are generally not appropriate.